# connect to mongodb production using robomongo client

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ubuntu

in my dev enviorment I use mlab as temp db, but now I have production db setup in my ubuntu server. I can run mongo in my terminal after I ssh into my server, now I'm having problem connecting it with my client software which is robomongo. What step I missed out?

Answer (score 0):

In your mongo (mongod) configuration file (default **/etc/mongod.conf**), you have to set the `net.bindIp` setting to `::,0.0.0.0` to bind to all IP addresses what can access to db or you can set only your pc ip address (robomongo belong to the pc) and your node server ip (localhost if nodeserver is the same with db server).